# Не могу разобраться с запросом в базу на обновления

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

view

```
 <?php foreach($orders as $order){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="left"><?php echo $order['order_id']; ?></td>
                    <td class="left"><?php echo $order['sum_date']; ?></td>
                    <td class="left"><?php echo $order['customer']; ?></td>
                    <td class="left"><a href="https://novaposhta.ua/tracking/?cargo_number=<?=$order['ttn']; ?>"  ><?php echo $order['ttn']; ?></a></td>
                    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="total" value="<?php echo $order['total']; ?>"></td>
                    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="currency" value="<?php echo $order['currency']; ?>"></td>
                    <td class="left"><?php echo $order['ttn_status']; ?></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?php echo $order['order_id'];?>">
                    <td></td>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tr>
```

controller

```
 if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )) {
        //$this->model_module_finance->update_finance_order($this->request->post);
        //$this->redirect($this->url->link('module/finance/payments_pending', 'customer_id=' . $customer_id . '&token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
    }
```

model

```
 public function update_finance_order(array $list){
    foreach ($list as $key => $val) {

        $query = ("UPDATE `" . DB_PREFIX . "finance_order` SET total = '" . $this->db->escape($list[$key]['total']) ."', currency = '" .  $this->db->escape($list[$key]['currency_value']).  "' WHERE order_id = '" . ($list[$key]['order_id']) ."'");
        $this->db->query($query);
        print_r($query);die;
    }
}
```

в controller приходят данные виде

```
Array ( [total] => 10 [currency] => 27.5 [order_id] => 6765 )
```

Comment: А что не так ? в контроллере видно что `total`, `currency`, `order_id` не в одном массиве, а каждый в своем `[0] => Array ( [total] => 59.5000 ) [1] => Array ( [currency] => 27.3500 ) [2] => Array ( [order_id] => 6405 ) [3] => Array ( [total] => 59.5000 )`, это в модели Вы и получаете. А почему так, тут уже пока я не знаю, либо что-то во вьюхе, либо в `$this->request->post['list']`

Comment: я переделал view and controller теперь приходят данные виде Array ( [total] => 10 [currency] => 27.5 [order_id] => 6765 ) но приходит один массив а остальные почему нет?

Comment: теперь похоже что они перезаписывают друг друга, вместо того что бы создавать массив, внутри которого будут массивы со значениями `total`, `currnency`, `order_id`. Да кстати, это фреймворк какой-то или свой велосипед ?

Comment: это opencart а что не так

Comment: смотрите я переделал вюшку теперь данные приходят виде Array
([0] => Array ( [total] => 59.5000 [currency] => 27.3500[order_id] => 6005 ) [1] => Array    (  [total] => 7.8000 [currency] => 27.5000       [order_id] => 6755   ) но с запросом на обновления что не так  

    [2] => Array
        (
            [total] => 67.0000
            [currency] => 27.5000
            [order_id] => 6727
        )

Comment: $query = ("UPDATE `" . DB_PREFIX . "finance_order` SET total = '" . $this->db->escape($order['total']) ."', currency = '" .  $this->db->escape($order['currency_value']).  "' WHERE order_id = '" . ($order['order_id']) ."'");

        print_r($query);die;

Comment: ответ UPDATE `oc_finance_order` SET total = '', currency = '' WHERE order_id = ''

Comment: Все не досмотрел все приходит Все спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что в данном случае, функция `update_finance_order` ожидает, что ей дадут параметр `$list`такой структуры

```
Array(
    [0] => Array (
        [total] => 59.5000,
        [currency] => 27.3500,
        [order_id] => 6405
    )
)
```